# How to change the mirror of macports

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion

I'm a newbie to OS X, and totally confused about the way macports works.

My question is, how to change the mirror or the sites where macports download the portfiles and distfiles.

The mirror I'm trying to use: http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/macports/

Should I change the sources.conf? But this mirror has no rsync protocol(I'm not really clear about what rsync protocol is >_<).

Or should I configure the macports.conf?

I know about the macports offical guide, but I'm not smart enough to figure this out.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation:
https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Mirrors

> The URL used to get Portfiles is set in ${prefix}/etc/macports/sources.conf

If you are new to OS X and/or MacPorts, please consider reading the introductory guide: http://guide.macports.org/

Comment: How do you edit the sources.conf, I keep getting readonly mode error.

Comment: `sudo vim /opt/local/etc/macports/sources.conf`

Answer (score 0):

The URL used to get Portfiles is set in `${prefix}/etc/macports/sources.conf`

https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Mirrors