# How to use a different mirror of macports rather than the official mirrors?

Tags: macos, macports, mirror

How to use a different mirror rather than the mirrors in the [list](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Mirrors)?

Well, I mean not only download `port.tar` from other mirror, like the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693375/how-to-change-the-mirror-of-macports), but also download packages from a different mirror.

I have noticed that when downloading packages, the `port` just download packages from [this link](http://jog.id.packages.macports.org/macports/packages/). But I don't know how to change the mirror it get packages from.

Comment: What is the reason you need to do this as that might help s to solve the issue

Comment: @Mark Not every corner of the world have direct access to macports. For those people who have got a osx but cannot connect macports, it is a miserable. I want to help do something.

Comment: Why can't you access macports as other mirrors could also have this issue?

Comment: @Mark China CERNET is just one of those networks.

Comment: or for example right now, rsync access to trac.macports.org times out (according to twitter, I'm not the only one seeing this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **/opt/local/etc/macports/archive_sites.conf** as root.

Add the following two lines:

```
    name    local_archives
    urls    http://jog.id.packages.macports.org/macports/packages/
```

You can also disable all the official archive mirrors by doing like this:

```
name    macports_archives

name    local_archives
urls    http://jog.id.packages.macports.org/macports/packages/
```